# Flutter secondaryAnimation not running

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am pushing a page called `SecondPage` onto the stack with the following code. The animation using `animation` runs as expected. When `SecondPage` appears, it slides up from the bottom of the screen.

When I'm looking at `SecondPage`, I push a `ThirdPage` on top of `SecondPage`. As I watch `ThirdPage` appear on the screen, I don't see `SecondPage` slide up as I expected based on the use of `secondaryAnimation` below. In fact, there is no animation of `SecondPage` at all during the transition to `ThirdPage`. `SecondPage` is just stationary while being covered by `ThirdPage`.

How do I get `SecondPage` to move up while `ThirdPage` appears?

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      return SecondPage();
    },
    transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
      return SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
          end: Offset.zero,
        ).animate(animation),
        child: SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset.zero,
            end: const Offset(0.0, -1.0),
          ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
          child: child,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SecondaryAnimation` won't get you this done. You should use `Stack` instead of making one child other.

Here is what you need.

```
transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      SlideTransition(
        position: Tween(begin: Offset(0, 1), end: Offset.zero).animate(animation),
        child: child,
      ),
      SlideTransition(
        position: Tween(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0, -1)).animate(animation),
        child: this,
      ),
    ],
  );
},
```

Answer (score -1):

## TL,DR

> The code of `SecondPage` you presented is fine as it barely has any differences from the demo given by `buildTransitions` method annotations, more information might be required of how the transition of `ThirdPage` is implemented to help figuring out what is going on there

## How `animation` and `secondaryAnimation` change during `Navigator` router stack changes

### Phase 1: `SecondPage` pushed to the top of `Navigator` router stack

In this phase, `animation` will continually increase to **1** from **0**, while `secondaryAnimation`  will remain as **0**

### Phase 2: `ThirdPage` pushed in

In this phase, `animation` will remain as **1** since `SecondPage` is still in the router stack, though covered by the topmost `ThirdPage`. On the other hand, `secondaryAnimation` come into work, it will increase to **1** from **0**, indicating that another new router is pushed in above the current `SecondPage`

### Phase 4: `MoreAndMorePage` pushed in

In this phase, `animation` and `secondaryAnimation` will both sustain **1** since `SecondPage` keeps disappearing from the top of the screen.

### Phase 3: `ThirdPage` poped out of `Navigator` router stack

Finally, `SecondPage` is comming back on the top of the screen. `animation` will remain **1** and `secondaryAnimation` decreases to **0** from **1**, just as the same as the final state of **Phase 1**

### Phase 4: `SecondPage` poped out

`animation` will decreases to **0** from **1**, and `secondaryAnimation` remains **0**